# SQL Server 2012 Results Grid

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to perform basic calculations on a results grid, such as column totals?

This would make it much easier to compare results when editing queries.

Comment: If you are talking about in SSMS the answer is no. It is just a grid.

Comment: What do you mean with "result grid". A relational database is made up of tables, rows and columns.

Comment: I was using Excel a while a go :)

Comment: You could do column totals in the query itself using `SUM()OVER()` or other aggregate functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming by results grid, you mean what you get when you do a select query such as 'SELECT * FROM TABLE' in SQL management studio. If this is the case, then no, you can't.

Best thing you can do is, use one of the aggregate functions on the column(s) you want to do the calculation on such as 'SELECT SUM(ColumnName) FROM TABLE' will give you the sum of the values in that column.

List of SQL aggregate functions: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: I thought so, but had to ask anyway. I can always export the results into Excel, but would be much faster to check the data if we can filter and do basic calculation operations directly in the results window.

Answer (score 1):

**No** you can not do the result like as you can do it in Excel. The results are shown in a grid, if you want to get the count or sum then you have to write the query for that by using functions like `COUNT()` and `SUM()`.